# Can I use Hyper-V on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, hyper-v

Through circumstances outside of my control, I am currently having to use Windows XP, on a machine with a current generation i5 processor, which obviously supports hyper-v.

Is there any way to make use of the hyper-v functionality to virtualize a more modern OS, or is this just not an option on XP?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to make use of the hyper-v functionality to
>   virtualize a more modern OS, or is this just not an option on XP?

Hyper-V can only be installed on Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012, and Windows Server 
2012 R2.  Feel free to install VMWare, Virtual PC 2007, or Virtual Box since you have limited yourself to only Windows Xp as the host operating system.

Previous versions of Windows Server did have a feature called Hyper-V this was a slightly different virtual machine then the current version.  Windows 7 had a version of `Virtual PC` called XP Mode which allowed the ( near ) seamless intergration of a Windows XP virtual machine to exist within Windows 7.

Comment: Actually, the Hyper-V role is available on Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2008 R2 as well.  Also, XP Mode was based on Virtual PC, which is not an earlier version of Hyper-V, being technically very different, being a Type 2 hypervisor, rather than a bare-metal Type 1.  And none of these are virtual machines - they are hypervisors that can run virtual machines.

Comment: @paradroid - I actually pointed out that previous versions of Windows Server had a version of Hyper-V.  XP Mode actually was based on Hyper-V.

Comment: No, the version of Hyper-V on 2008 and 2008 R2 were just earlier versions, but not architecturally different to the current version.  XP Mode runs on Windows Virtual PC and not Hyper-V, which is very different.  Virtual PC runs within the host OS and not under it.

Comment: @paradroid - I stand corrected about Windows XP, but I never said the version of Hyper-V in previous versions of Windows Server were architecturally different I simply said they were slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible as far as I know. Hyper-V was initially released shortly after Windows Vista/Server 2008.

As you've already stated; your processor supports visualization so you would be able to run any modern OS in VMWare Workstation/Player or VirtualBox instead.

Comment: Would VMWare/VirtualBox make use of the hardware in the same way as hyper-v though? My understanding was that hyper-v was able to use the hardware in ways other kinds of virtualization software cannot, giving you extra performance etc

Comment: I'm not sure of the ins and outs of the different visualization platforms. We use the free Hyper-V Server 2012 within our company and the features it brings in a clustered environment are fantastic. Although I have used all three soltions, on 8.1 admin machine I much prefer VMWare Workstation over the Hyper-V and I personally haven't noticed any performance issues over Hyper-V... This article shows the subtle differences in performance.  http://packageology.com/2012/08/windows-8-hyper-v-vmware-workstation-9/

Comment: @JMK - You will have to research what features VMWare or Virtual Box does or does not have compared to Hyper-V. In the end those are the two major choices, I don't know of an additional choice, when it comes to feature rich virtual machine software.  Since you have to use Windows XP you will be unable to use Hyper-V

Answer (score 0):

Install Windows 8 and then virtualize XP. XP is almost worthless as a host OS, flip it around, use a modern OS as the host and then virtualize the obsolete OS.